# Getting more friendly error messages in angularjs apps

Tags: angularjs

I have written a simple Angular-js app as below:

```
angular.module("myApp",['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){

  $routeProvider
  .when('/',{
    name:'route1',
  controller:'Route1Ctrl',
  template:'partials/route1.tpl.html'
  })

.otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});

}])

.controller('Route1Ctrl',['$scope',function($scope){


}});
```

The app fails to load and the only error message that I can see in the chrome console box is:

```
Uncaught objet
```

What can I do to get more usable error messages ?

Comment: Wrap the entire thing in `try {..your code here..} catch (e) { alert ("I'm sorry Dave, I am afraid I can't do that."); exit(); }`

Comment: The error turned out to be that angular was not able to locate the myApp module because there was a typo in the path. It would still help  to get a more friendlier error message. the Try..catch block did not help cause javascript could not get to those lines..

Comment: @JamesHans, This is a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5568) with chrome browsers.

Comment: Very late but just for knowledge.. if you are looking for friendly error message in angular js you should use angular.js file instead of minified angular js file.

Answer (score 0):

instead of template: you must use **templateUrl**

Comment: I fixed that long back..but that was not the point.. the point as to get better error message.. thx though